# InCallService speakerphone issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently making a calling app for Android and I've run into an issue. I want to let the user activate speakerphone (also bluetooth etc) and mute their microphone from the custom call UI. However, I can't seem to figure out how I can call the setAudioRoute method in my InCallService. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Please share more information on your specific problem, any code examples etc, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask